# I don't understand why this simple statement isn't working

Tags: java, string, null

So I'm basically finished with a program, and at the end of it I'm printing Strings from an array to a file.  The array may contain null values, so I'm checking for null before I print, but I keep ending up with 1 null at the very end of the file...

Here's the code I'm using to check for null

```
for(int i=0;i<array2.length;i++)
{
    if(array2[i] != null)
        out.println(array2[i]);
}
```

I know that the array contains multiple instances of null, but only 1 is being printed.  I tried using the debugger and when array2[i] == null, it still entered the conditional statement...

So I added a println statement to help me see what's going on.  It now looks like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<array2.length;i++)
        {
            if(array2[i] != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Adding " + array2[i]);
                out.println(array2[i]);
            }
```

Just after printing all the String values to the console, it prints "Adding null" so I know it's happening here in this if statement.  Why is this happening???

Comment: nothing seems wrong with the statement by itself - could it be that the value of the string which is printed is actually "null", instead of the string being null?

Comment: ...or might you have one more 'println' call after the loop?

Comment: Can you post all your code? This looks like it should work.

Comment: nylarlathotep was right!  I changed the statement to also check for the String "null" and now it's no longer printing.  Now I just need to figure out how that null got in there...

Answer (score 1):

The debugger is not always clear as to whether it has entered an `if` condition or not.  I don't believe this code is entering the if condition which it might appear it is and your `null` is probably coming from another line of code.

You could write the code as

```
for(ElementType e: array2.length)
    if(e != null)
        out.println("[" + e+ ']'); // extra text for debugging.
// I suspect your `null` will still be on a line of its own
```

Answer (score -2):

Arent you also missing a set of brakets for the if statement??

```
for(int i=0;i<array2.length;i++) 
{ 
  if(array2[i] != null) 
  {
    out.println(array2[i]); 
  }
}
```

Comment: If the code in the if is only one line the braces are optional.

Comment: well, no.  If it's a 1-line conditional, you don't necessarily need the brackets

Comment: @RyanDavis: While that's certainly true, I would personally recommend *always* using them, to avoid insidious bugs.

Comment: Looks like I learned something new today also! Never tried to not use brackets before!

Comment: @JavaGeek: `for(int i=0;i<array2.length;i++) if(array2[i] != null) out.println(array2[i]);` is also valid, but best left for quick debugging.

Comment: Yeah, whilst this is interesting to know. I think it is bad practice, difficult to debug and also just not as easy to read which could cause issues.